# What's different from HTTP2-settings and connection preface

Tags: http2

from the [HTTP/2 protocol](https://httpwg.github.io/specs/rfc7540.html)

> The content of the HTTP2-Settings header field is the payload of a SETTINGS frame (Section 6.5)

and

> Upon receiving the 101 response, the client MUST send a connection preface (Section 3.5), which includes a SETTINGS frame

My question is why client send SETTINGS frame twice to server? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP/2 puts a lot of emphasis on exchanging SETTINGS before anything else, so I have the impression that the HTTP2-Settings is for informing the server of the client's conditions before the server even accepts to switch to HTTP/2.

The second SETTINGS frame is probably for uniformity, so that once the upgrade from HTTP/1.1 is completed there be a uniform HTTP/2 session starting with SETTINGS, the same that would be over TLS+ALPN or through plain HTTP/2 with previous knowledge. The spec doesn't say which settings should go in any of the frames, AFAICT, so one of them can be empty (which is actually stated by the spec, section 3.5).

This redundancy is a small cost to pay: 9 bytes per connection, compared with the complications that it would carry to have slightly different implementations of HTTP/2 for the cases when there is an upgrade from HTTP/1.1 vs the cases when there is not.

Notice that while some tools will actually use HTTP/2 over plain connections, the really interesting cases, i.e., browsers, will use TLS+ALPN always.

Comment: Is it allowed for the server to send `SETTINGS` frame before client sends `SETTINGS` frame to the server?